# How to change date format in outlook when I am sending mail linked with Excel data?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

Can someone help me out here with formatting date when I am sending email? In **Cell 8** I have date but when I'm sending email date will show as 10/03/2016 but I wanted to show date as 03-Oct-2016. I tried putting code as `& Format(Date, "dd/mmm/yy")` but when I run the program it will show today's date next to 10/03/2016.

**Please see below my coding:**

```
## "Full Name      :  " & Cells(i, 6) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

        "Nationality    : " & Cells(i, 7) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Departure/Arrival  Date : " & Cells(i, 8) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Airline        : " & Cells(i, 9) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Flight Number  : " & Cells(i, 10) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Departure/Arrival Time : " & Cells(i, 11) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Escort required: " & Cells(i, 14) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        " " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        " Contact Number: " & Cells(i, 12) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _ ##
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
"Departure/Arrival  Date : " & Cells(i, 8) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
```

to

```
"Departure/Arrival  Date : " & Format(Cells(i, 8), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
```

Comment: Finally i have done it. i have codded as                                          "Departure/Arrival  Date : " & "" & Format(Cells(i, 8), "dd-mmm-yy") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

Comment: @ArunThoras - concatenating an empty string to a string just returns the original string so `"Departure/Arrival Date : " & "" &` is exactly the same as `"Departure/Arrival Date : " &`.  It's a bit like saying `x + y` instead of `x + 0 + y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, can you help me out on that particular line how to make it bold and red please.

Comment: @ArunThoras - Sorry - can't help with formatting in Outlook - I've never tried to use Outlook VBA.

Comment: i have data in Excel and when i run the program it will send mail, but i need that line to be bold when i run program.

Comment: @ArunThoras - I assume that all you are doing with Excel is getting the **values** of certain cells and generating a string, and then using that string as the body of an email.  The string therefore needs to be formatted within the email, and that will require knowledge of the Outlook commands to format text (specifically how to format **portions** of a text string).  So, as I said, I have never tried to use Outlook VBA (even via an Outlook application invoked from within Excel) so I won't be able to help with that formatting.